# Open / Create Sqlite database in different folder

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to create sqlite database in the selected directory, but can`t do this. Every time when I try to create db using path to folder I get error SQLITE_CANTOPEN

The code below:

The function to create DB:

```
using database = std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, decltype(&sqlite3_close)>;
database open_database(const char* name)
{
    sqlite3* db = nullptr;
    int rc = sqlite3_open(name, &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::string S = (std::string)"Unable to open database '" + name + "': " +
            sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        throw std::exception(S.c_str());
    }
    return database{ db, sqlite3_close };

}
```

The following code works:

```
open_database("file:testMY_db.sqlite?cache=shared");
open_database("testMY_db.sqlite");
```

The code below throw exception: SQLITE_CANTOPEN .

```
open_database("file:///C:/Users/Андрей/Desktop/test_db.sqlite?cache=shared");
open_database("file:///C:/Users/Андрей/Desktop/test_db.sqlite");
open_database("file:/C:/Users/Андрей/Desktop/test_db.sqlite?cmode=rw");
```

If anybody got such problem or know how tofix it please healp me.

Comment: What is the encoding that your editor used for your source code file?

Comment: @CL Cyrillic (Windows) - Codepage 1251